# JSON creation by splitting a string?

Tags: java, json, spring-rest, jsonparser

So I have a situation where I am fetching some data from a database which I can't change/update. So my data from 2 columns coming like this:

**For example**:

```
        Column1             Column2
Row 1: hello.how.are.you    Gracie
Row 2: hello.how.is.she     John
Row 3: hello.how.is.he      Gurinder   
Row 4: hello.from.me        Singh
```

So I need to create a JSON which will look like:

```
{  
   "hello":{  
      "how":{  
         "are":{  
            "you":"Gracie"
         },
         "is":{  
            "he":"Gurinder",
            "she":"John"
         }
      },
      "from":{  
         "me":"Singh"
      }
   }
}
```

I want some optimize way to create my JSON. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String > stringList = new ArrayList();
    stringList.add("hello.how.are.you");
    stringList.add("hello.how.is.she");
    stringList.add("hello.how.is.he");
    stringList.add("hello.from.me");

    JSONObject response = new JSONObject();

    for (String str : stringList) {

            String[] keys = str.split("\\.");

            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

                if (response.has(keys[i])) {

                } else {
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject()
                    response.append(keys[i], jsonObject2);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am doing something like this and trying to solve.

Comment: So what did you try? Which part of this task presents a problem to you?

Comment: So first I am splitting the first column by "." and using JsonObject Class of org.json and trying to append it. But it's not working.

Comment: Please show the code that is not working

Comment: Don't post a problem on SO without posting an attempted solution as well, and asking what's wrong with your solution. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: And before trying to find an "optimized" way, try just to find "a way". Usually, it's fastenough, because computers are incredibly fast.

Comment: @Gurinder If my answer is correct you should accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're using for input needs to hold all of the data (Including Column 2). Let's say the `input` variable is a `HashMap<String, String>` equal to

```
{
    "hello.how.are.you" : "Gracie",
    ...
}
```

At the moment, your code looks like its on track. The issue is, you're appending to `response`, when you want to append to some value deep in the JSON tree.

```
JSONObject parent = response;
for(...) {
    // If there's no JSON there, just make it
    if( !parent.has(keys[i]) ) {
        // It's not already in there, so let's make it
        parent.put(keys[i], new JSONObject()); // response["hello"] = {}
    }
    // Now, look at how this works. If keys = ["hello", "how", "are", "you"],
    // Then when i == 0, parent <= response["hello"]
    // That way you do response["hello"].append("how", {}) on the next iteration
    parent = (JSONObject)parent.get(keys[i]);
}
```

You'll also need to handle the tail case, which you can do with something like

```
if( i == keys.length - 1 ) {
    parent.put(keys[i], input.get(str)); // str = "hello.how.are.you"
    // input.get("hello.how.are.you") == "Gracie"
} else ...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! But this code wouldn't work, this above code will create "hello", "are", "how",  "you" as a separate structure {"how":[{}],"are":[{}],"hello":[{}],"you":[{}]} like this. I want hello.how.are.you should be {  
   "hello":{  
      "how":{  
         "are":{  
            "you":"Gracie"
         },
         "is":{  
            "he":"Gurinder",
            "she":"John"
         }
      },
      "from":{  
         "me":"Singh"
      }
   }
}

They should be present internally not parallelly.

Comment: if (!target.has(key)) {
                    target.put(key, new JSONObject());
                }

                target = target.getJSONObject(key);

This approach is working. I tried this one. But if i use your code => parent.append(keys[i], new JSONObject()); Its creating new json object on parallel level

Comment: Ah, that's a library-specific quirk. I'll update my code, I haven't used the JSONObject library so I just imitated the function call you used.

Comment: Does `.get` still work, or does that have to be `.getJSONObject`? I imagine `.get` works. Regardless, it's just a lil update from `append` to `put`. The former must've implicitly instantiated a JSONArray as opposed to throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by using this approach :

```
    public static void main(String... r) {

    String[] keys = myString.split("//.");

    JSONObject target = new JSONObject();

    int lastValueIndex = keys.length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        String key = keys[i];

        if (!target.has(key) && (lastValueIndex == i)) {

            target.put(key, myValue);

            break;

        } else if (!target.has(key)) {
            target.put(key, new JSONObject());
        }

        target = target.getJSONObject(key);

    }

}
```

Try your own way before using my code, Thanks!